# Login gets lost with Navigation IE in Powershell aspx

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, aspx-user-control

I am trying to automate a website interaction.

I can login programatically without issue.

Once I login I get to a page with a toolbar. When I hover over one of the options of the toolbar, the bottom of the ie screen displays a url that ends with .aspx.

When I navigate using $ie.navigate

> $ie.Navigate("https://dcr.alleghenycounty.us/Civil/Filing/InitialCaseFiling.aspx")

, it redirects me to a page that tells me I need to log in. When I click manually works properly. There is no element for the drop down that I click on.

I am concerned that the navigate function causes the page to lose some kind of cookie.
I tried invoke-webrequest but it didn't do anything in the browser.
I tried appending the 2048 tag in the navigate command to open in new window.

Is there an alternate method of opening an .aspx?

I need to use powershell. I need to use internet explorer.
[image]

Comment: "When I click it works properly." - what happens when you `click()` it programmatically?

Comment: The toolbar pulls its contents from some database and the element isn't visible when I inspect the page source

Comment: Open Dev Tools (F12), then locate and identify the element

Comment: Is that webpage is from the same site or it is a different site? If possible, can you try to share the sample code? You can remove the private information from your code or replace it with the dummy information. It can help us to check whether there is an issue with the code.